# Facebook PHP SDK login and localhost

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to set FB SDK to work in my localhost. I made a test App and set it  site URL and App Domain to http://localhost, but it doesn't work. I see this error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in  the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Is there a way  FB SDK work on localhost ? I see another questions here, but same solutions does not work

Comment: The solution for me turned out to be simple enough... FB won't allow a TLD as the domain name. But you can use something like `fb.localhost` or `my.test`. Ensure you've added it in both the places the message describes.

Comment: @Chris this isn't my question, I'm just leaving a helpful comment, but I don't have time to go into a detailed answer :D Someone else can have it!

Comment: @rjdown, oops, I misread your user name!

Answer (score 0):

In the app "Settings", under "App Domains" you should put `localhost`. Also, below where it says "Website" and "Site URL", you should put `http://localhost/`. If there is no "Website" and "Site URL" section, press "Add Platform" and choose "Website". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is this. You can create virtual host with same domain name like this:
 - if your site is `site.com`, create virtual host with name something like `local.site.com`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Facebook SDK , Facebook has limited it to secure connections using https.

So, fir local development; you will need to setup a virtual host in a fictional name and add it to your Facebook app and don't forget to setup the SSL on the virtual host.

Happy coding